# javascript parsing not working document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code in the source code of the page:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="user" href="#">Tom</a>
```

I tried to parse the string "Tom" with this code:

```
var username = document.getElementsByClassName("user").innerHTML;
alert(username);
```

But the username variable was undefined, what is the problem with the code?
I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: +1 for not wanting to use jQ for something like this... It shows that you're willing to put in the effort, learning to use JS and the (clunky) DOM API yourself, rather than relying on an often abused tool

Answer (score 4):

Look at the name of the DOM method: *getElement**s**ByClassName*. It's a plural, so can, and most likely will, return more than 1 element.
These elements will be stored in a array like object (instance of `NodeList`).

```
var usernames = document.getElementsByClassName('user');
var first = usernames[0];
```

But really, `getElementsByClassName` is not as well supported, it would be preferable to use `querySelectorAll` (compare [the `querySelector` support](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) support with that of [the `getElementsByClassName`](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname), especially in IE)

```
var usernames = document.querySelectorAll('.user');
var first = usernames[0];
```

Besides, using these selectors, you can bypass having to query the entire DOM:

```
var username = document.querySelector('.user');//gets just one
```

Note:
Details on [the `NodeList` class on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
Do note that some versions of FireFox will return an object that *is not called `NodeList`*, but Mozilla's own superset of the DOM API, which extends the `NodeList` constructor. I can't recall what that object is called ATM, but I'll get back in touch once I remember

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `document.getElementById`, the `document.getElementsByClassName` method returns an array of elements which have your specified class. In this case, you might want to pick the first of them.

```
var username = document.getElementsByClassName("user")[0].innerHTML;
alert(username);
```

You have missed `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the [0] to get the first element.

```
var username = document.getElementsByClassName("user")[0].innerHTML;
```